# difference between merise and uml functionally and in methodical level

Tags: uml

I have a question about the difference between UML and merise first functionally and in methodical level. Can you please explain to me this difference?

Comment: What is merise? Can you provide a link?

Comment: A place in Estonia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise,_Estonia

Comment: And a french forum: http://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-287558-comparaison-uml-merise It looks like this is France only.

Comment: UML has no methodology. It's a language. So I guess your question is pointless.

Comment: @ThomasKilian It IS a difference, isn't it?

Comment: If you are looking for french tools, look for LePus3, IT is the counterpart of UML, and a very powerful one.

Comment: @Gangnus Every two things which are not the same are different (I guess that would also be the definition for "different"). An egg is not an apple. Comparison pointless. The first time I heard of Lepus3. Also a french product. They must live on a different planet ;-)

Comment: @ThomasKilian I merely think, that your comment is a correct answer. The question was "what difference?" You said: "Merise is a methodology, UML is a language." But you should enlarge it somehow to put as an answer :-). ... As for LePus3, it has English wiki page, manual, and some opensource tool, too. And IMHO, it is extremely interesting - small, strict and powerful.

Comment: @Gangnus I have added it as answer. I did not mean that either is of lower value, just having French roots (at least Merise). But the French have an attitude to reinvent everything in French (cliquez ici).

Answer (score 2):

You can not compare Merise with UML. [Merise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merise) is a methodology. UML is a language.

I don't know Merise, to be honest. So I can relate UML to [RUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_Unified_Process), which is also a methodology. RUP tells you how to advance in a project. It uses UML to express certain aspects of this process. I guess Merise could also use UML to express parts of the process description (if it does not do already).

Comment: Thank you. I think, if something is obvious for you, very often, no, almost always it is unknown for somebody else.

Comment: @Gangnus Hehe. I just used that term the last days in a different context ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would also add to Thomas answer, that Merise can only design databases models, while UML is mainly used for object-oriented design.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post;](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the difference that exists between them can lead us to work with both of them. One can be a complement of the other.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

merise can design only database and about UML mainly used for OOD